# JS not working on first load - works after a refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing a fairly simply thing in JS: I'm testing if an element (based on a Class Name) contains a string.

I think the reason it's not working is because the element is rendered on the page via a HTTPS request separate to the onload event. (Sort of like an embedded/iFrame type thing).

Example of the script that I have:

```
(function($) {

//Only run on a specific page.
if(window.location.href.indexOf("SpecificPageImRunningOn") > -1) {

    //Wait for 3 seconds before running this script, to allow content to load
    setTimeout(function(){

        //Check if a class contains a string "Foobar"
        if($('.aSpecificClass').text().indexOf('Foobar') != -1){
            alert("Yes!");
        }
        else{
            alert("No!");
        }

    }, 3000);

}

})(jQuery);
```

When I test this the first time round (fresh browser- cleared cache), it does not work as expected.

Once I refresh, it works perfectly well.

I have tried triggering the function manually (via clicking a button after everything has loaded) and it still did not behave any differently. It did not work at all on the first load.

I have also tried doing a single forced refresh by setting a cookie and that did not seem to make any difference.

I think I'm missing something obvious!

[image: Test]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix this by checking for window.model (the content that loads within the frame that we're targetting) over and over again every 100ms before running the actions.

Sample code:

```
(function($) {

//Only run on a specific page.
if(window.location.href.indexOf("SpecificPageImRunningOn") > -1) {

    function holdOnRecheck() {
        //check if window.model has been defined and that it is not Null before running code. If conditions are not met, wait for 100ms then run the function holdOnRecheck again.
        if (window.model !== undefined && window.model !== null)
        {
            //window model has loaded - good. Now check if the content we are targetting in particular within the model has loaded (judging by its length). If not, wait for 100ms then run the function holdOnRecheck again.
            if (window.model.ABC.length > 0)
            {
                //If you got this far, it's safe to assume that the content has loaded within the model, so you can run whatever you want on the content and it should do something.
                if($('.aSpecificClass').text().indexOf('Foobar') != -1){
                    alert("Yes!");
                }
                else{
                    alert("No!");
                }
                //finish by hiding loading spinner
                document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
            }
            else
            {
                window.setTimeout(holdOnRecheck, 100); 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            window.setTimeout(holdOnRecheck, 100); 
        }
    }   

}
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't rely on a timeout to wait for an element to become ready. The first time you run it, the element is not ready at the time, while the second time it is because it was cached after the first run.

Either put the script at the bottom of the page, before you close the `body` tag, or use [`$(document).ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) callback to run once once DOM is ready.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried $(document).ready() and unfortunately this hasn't changed the behaviour. I expect this is because the element I'm investigating is an external resource.

Comment: Oh, it's external, sorry I missed that. In that case you need to use a listener on that extenal element, instead of the document (like `$('iframe').ready()`). You should never rely on a single timeout.

Comment: Actually, the above comment may not be true, based on the docs (but I could swear I've used it long ago and it worked): `"As of jQuery 3.0, only the first syntax is recommended; the other syntaxes still work but are deprecated. This is because the selection has no bearing on the behavior of the .ready() method, which is inefficient and can lead to incorrect assumptions about the method's behavior. For example, the third syntax works with "document" which selects nothing. The fourth syntax waits for the document to be ready but implies (incorrectly) that it waits for images to become ready."`

Comment: Can you render your external element using something that allows a callback, like `.load()`?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm confined to a proprietary CMS. So I can add functions but I can't play with the core functions. I do know that the CMS fires off a function called "doneLoading" when the external content is loaded. Does that help in any way? :)

Comment: Yes! Do a research on that event, see what it sends, where you need to listen to it and a simple [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful. :-) I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

As @Shomz pointed out, `setTimeout` is not a good way to do what you want. There are two possible ways I recommend:

**Using jQuery document ready event**

```js
//Only run on a specific page.
if(window.location.href.indexOf("SpecificPageImRunningOn") > -1) {
   $(function() {
      //Check if a class contains a string "Foobar"
      if($('.aSpecificClass').text().indexOf('Foobar') != -1){
         alert("Yes!");
      }
      else {
         alert("No!");
      }
   });
}
```

**Using window load event**

This is when the ready function does not work well, like when you are trying to verify if the element is a external resource as image:

```js
//Only run on a specific page.
if(window.location.href.indexOf("SpecificPageImRunningOn") > -1) {
   $(window).on("load", function() {
      //Check if a class contains a string "Foobar"
      if($('.aSpecificClass').text().indexOf('Foobar') != -1){
         alert("Yes!");
      }
      else {
         alert("No!");
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: To differentiate from the other way using window load.